# Update all dictionary values with different ids

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to design an auto-generated dictionary template.

The format of dictionary is like: `{'google_drive': {'services': []}, 'dropbox': {'services': []}, 'test': {'services': []}}`

All keys have same value `{'services': []}` and their value ids/addresses should be different. The problem now is all values are the same.

```
# init function has an array ["google_drive", "dropbox", "test"] 
# so that all the key-value pairs can be created automatically
test = CloudInfo().init().config_info
print(id(test["google_drive"]["services"]))
print(id(test["dropbox"]["services"]))
print(id(test["test"]["services"]))
```

**Output**

```
2382756081216
2382756081216
2382756081216
```

And I have found the problem in my encapsulated method:

```
def update_all_value(self, keys, value):
    __keys = keys
    __dict = self.__dict
    __value = value
    if __keys is not None:
        for key in __keys:
            if key in __dict:
                __dict.update({key: __value})
        self.__dict = __dict
    return self
```

All keys have pointed to single variable `__value`.

If I changed `__dict.update({key: __value})` as `__dict.update({key: {'services': []}})`,  dictionary value are different ids. But the function is not reusable.

Is there any good solution that can update all dictionary values with different ids and keep the input parameter `value` working?

Comment: You can create a class that inherits from `dict`, and add the desired behavior int its `__init__()` method.

Comment: Thank you. Based on your suggestion, I have added class `AddrSol` which inherits from dict and has one attribute `variable`. In the update method, I have changed `__dict.update({key: AddrSol(value).variable})`. The ids is still the same. Do you know where is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#defaultdict-objects):

```py
from collections import defaultdict
import copy

template = {'services': []}
test = defaultdict(lambda: copy.deepcopy(template))
print(id(test["google_drive"]["services"]))
# 2546846465416
print(id(test["dropbox"]["services"]))
# 2546847840648
print(id(test["test"]["services"]))
# 2545171504392
```

Comment: I understand your solution but all the ids will be same if you declare a variable `a = {'services': []}` and add that a to ` test = defaultdict(lambda: a)`.

Comment: @DiWang I have edited the example to work around that with [`copy.deepcopy`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy).

Comment: Yes, the function `copy.deepcopy` is the solution I want.  Thank you very much for helping me with your wide knowledge. It is a great help for me. Again really appreciate it!